# Avoid printing table name in column name while using beeline

Tags: sql, select, hive, beeline

While using hive in beeline an using simple `select` query I would like to return table ***without*** table name in column name as a default.

## Example

### Data

On example of a simple table *[(TutorialsPoint)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hive/hive_create_table.htm)*:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee ( eid int, name String,
salary String, destination String)
COMMENT 'Employee details'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

The `SELECT` query returns:

```
SELECT * FROM employee;
+---------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+--+
| employee.eid  | employee.name  | employee.salary  | employee.destination  |
+---------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+--+
+---------------+----------------+------------------+-----------------------+--+
```

## Desired results

The desired results are achieved with use of **`AS`**:

```
SELECT eid AS eid, name AS name, salary AS salary, 
       destination AS destination FROM employee;

+------+-------+---------+--------------+--+
| eid  | name  | salary  | destination  |
+------+-------+---------+--------------+--+
+------+-------+---------+--------------+--+
```

## Problem

I would like to avoid typing **`AS`** each time I run `select` query and return results without table names in column names as default behaviour.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false`

[Configuration Properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Configuration+Properties)

#### Demo

```
hive> create table t (i int,j int,k int);
hive> select * from t;
```

---

```
t.i t.j t.k
```

---

```
hive> set hive.resultset.use.unique.column.names=false;
hive> select * from t;
```

---

```
i   j   k
```