# Show only column name in a HUE hive query

Tags: hive, hue

So in Hue I've entered a simple query(has to be as simple as possible, as others will run it too) to just get a limit of 20 records. The query is:

Select * from tablename Limit 20

The problem is that the query returns column names in this format: tablename.columnname

I need JUST the column name to be returned, NOT the table name referenced at all. How is this achieved without going into a large "from" statement spelling out all of the columns(only other way I currently know)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i dont think its possible - others can comment. Meanwhile you can use column spelt out like `select col1,col2... from table`.

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't ideal as many of the tables have 50+ columns...

Comment: Do a `describe tab` - copy the result into xl. get the list form XL.

Comment: try this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43112981/9477843)

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but you could do a right click on the '*' of SELECT * and then expand all the column names:

[image]